# How to fetch data from an react?

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    users: [],
    error: null
  };
  fetchUers() {
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) =>
        this.setState({
          users: data,
          isLoading: false
        })
      )
      .catch((error) => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchUers();
  }
  render() {
    const { isLoading, users, error } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1> random user</h1>
        {error ? <p> {error.message} </p> : null}
        {isLoading ? (
          users.map((user) => {
            const { Image, title, first, last, Gender, address, cell } = user;
            return (
              <div key={username}>
                <p>Image :{Image}</p>
                <p>title :{title}</p>
                <p>first :{first}</p>
                <p>last :{last}</p>
                <p>Gender :{Gender}</p>
                <p>address :{address}</p>
                <p>cell :{cell}</p>
                <hr />
              </div>
            );
          })
        ) : (
          <h3> loading....</h3>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Tried to fetch data from react, but unable to fetch data, tried to fetch from an api for Image, title, first, last, Gender, address, cell

Tried to fetch data from react, but unable to fetch data, tried to fetch from an api for Image, title, first, last, Gender, address, cell
Tried to fetch data from react, but unable to fetch data, tried to fetch from an api for Image, title, first, last, Gender, address, cell

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-microservice-msysy?file=/src/App.js

Comment: the context - "this" will not work here. You have to bind it, or pass a variable referencing "this" before calling method fetch()

Comment: thanks for the answer,if possible can you share the code for it,it would be very helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```js
  fetchUers() {
    const self = this;
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) =>
        self.setState({
          users: data,
          isLoading: false
        })
      )
      .catch((error) => self.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }
```

Option 2:

```js
  
  fetchUers() {
    const handleSuccess = data => {
      this.setState({
        users: data,
        isLoading: false
      });
    }.bind(this);
 
    const handleError = error => {
      this.setState({ error, isLoading: false });
    }.bind(this);

    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(handleSuccess)
      .catch(handleError);
  }
```